# Issue upgrade angular 4 to angular 5 from Visual Studio template

Tags: angular, npm, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to update Angular from version 4 to version 5 that is provided by the template in Visual Studio 2017 (File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Core Web Application -> Angular).

By default, it seems all the angular packages are 4.2.5.  As I'm a novice with Angular, I'd prefer to be on the version for tutorials provided at Angular.IO.  I've tried the following tutorials to get this up to date:

- http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/

The tutorials follows the path of:

1. Create new ASP.NET Core 2 Web Application with Angular chosen as the template
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Open node.js command prompt or powershell as administrator
4. Navigate to the project folder containing `packages.json`
5. Run `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
6. Run `ncu -u`
7. Reopen Visual Studio
8. If packages are still pointing to Angular 4, delete `package-lock.json`, then repeat steps 1-7
9. Fix some code issues at outlined in the article

I've tried these steps multiple times in new projects and it never works for me.  I thought maybe it could just be a UI issue and it's not updating it, so I went and put `HttpClientModule` with the import of `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` inside of the `app.shared.module.ts` file, but it results with this error:

> ERROR in C:/Users/kandres/~/@angular/common/esm5/http.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'C:\Users\\node_modules\@angular\common\esm5'
>
> @ C:/Users//~/@angular/common/esm5/http.js 6:0-100
>
> @ ./ClientApp/app/app.shared.module.ts
>
> @ ./ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ts
>
> @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
>
> @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts

along with 6 other similar errors for `rxjs/Observable`, `rxjs/observable/of`, `rxjs/operator/concatMap`, `rxjs/operator/filter`, `rxjx/operator/map`, and `@angular/core` (again).

When I run `npm install -g npm-check-updates` I get an error that says:

> npm WARN npm@3.10.10 had bundled packages that do not match the required version(s).  They have been replaced with non-bundled versions.

When I run `ncu -u` every time it says `aspnet-webpack ^2.0.1 -> ^2.0.3`.  I can rerun that command multiple times and get that same message.  If I manually change packages.json to make that update, `ncu -u` says that all the packages are up to date.

The result of all of this doesn't make an change though for my project.  All my dependencies for angular 4 still point to version 4.2.5.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you want to use Angular 5 with the new Core template, start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/). Then read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio) on how to use the newly installed template.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work fine for what I need.

Comment: Before running update, make sure delete file `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, then delete `package-lock.json` after updating.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more detailed explanation, hopefully it would be useful.

1. Make sure *** Microsoft.NET Core SDK 2.1.xxx**   - [rc | preview | beta] candidates are uninstalled. Those come with new templates and will create asp .net core 2.1 - [rc | preview | beta] applications.  **Microsoft.NET Core SDK 2.1.xxx ***
2. Follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0#installation) to install the latest dotnet template separately
3. Execute a dotnet new angular
   Check the generated structure. package.json shall be under ClientApp folder and there would be a lot of references to Angular 5.2.0
4. For development purposes, make sure  that **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development**
5. Everything else is pretty much the same:

   **dotnet restore**

   **dotnet run**